# Read query takes too long in Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I try to update my redshift via lambda function that gonna update any changes in record in near real-time with this query

```
 UPDATE user_activity SET action = 'view',property_key, WHERE activity_id = '12345678'
```

and then I try to query them to show the result

```
SELECT * FROM user_activity WHERE activity_id = '12345678'
```

but these never finished. they keep running in queue and I have to terminate these queries to stop them.

I can tun INSERT and DELETE query normally which were completed in less than 1 second

So, what is the cause of this problem and how can I fix it?

Edit: more information

- Both UPDATE and SELECT query are work fine when I run on query editor. This problem were found only when I run query via Lambda function.
- In lambda, I connected to redshift via python library called sqlalchemy

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are direct connecting to Redshift and therefore are limited by the 15min Lambda timeout, right?  No use of Redshift Data API here, right?

I'd guess that there is a lock impeding the execution of the COMMIT of the UPDATE.  Check STV_LOCKS to ensure that some other process doesn't have an exclusive lock on the table. If there is ensure that all data modification processes COMMIT or ROLLBACK in a timely manner.

Comment: I've already checked STV_LOCKS and there's no record. I set Lambda timeout to around 6 mins since the SELECT query should not be takes more than 1 min (according to time that it takes in query editor)

Comment: There are a number of ways things could be going sideways.  I'd suggest starting at the beginning of the query process and see how for the query gets.  Does it get into a queue?  Does it start executing? Does it finish? Are the results produced? Etc? Knowing where it stalls will help narrow down the possibilities.